# Threejs Loads of the same Plane Mesh

Tags: three.js

Ive wrote a simple 3d dungeon generator using Threejs, but since i use alot of spotlights for torches in the dungeon im starting to get a FPS drop.

I know the light is the problem but before i tackle the light issue, i was thinking it could be possible to optimize the level. The level is made only by using a plane 200x200 with a wall texture. Ive read about instancing, is that what i want in this scenario ? Walls wont move. If they move i can make separate meshes for the moving ones.

For the lights im using LambertMaterial, should be the fastest one, but besides that ive done nothing to improve performance on that matter. Ive tryed to bake the room lights into the textures with this https://github.com/mem1b/lightbaking but failed.

So in the end, Is instancing the aproach to optimize the level polygons ? I read lttle bout it could not fully understand.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have 100 torches distributed on a flat wall. Each one of them pretty much only affects the part of the wall that it's closest to, area wise this would be 1/100th of the wall.

Now what if you divide this wall into a struct `wall segment` + `torch`. Instead of giving the global scene all 100 lights, you'd give each light segment a single local light.

Cool, now if you render the entire wall, you get 100 lights at the cost of one... computationally, but you also introduce 100 draw calls instead of one.

Instancing would help here. You could instance your wall segment geometry, and then for each instance set a light attribute instead of a uniform.

This way you could draw 100 lights on 100 light segments in one draw call. This would be much faster than drawing stuff 100 times.

Comment: This looks like a good aproach is there any example on how to do that division ?